# Why am I getting an ArgumentError on ActiveRecord find methods after upgrading to Ruby 3, but only on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After upgrading to Ruby 3.0.0 on my local machine, I can go to the console and enter:

```
User.find(1)
```

and it returns a user

After pushing to heroku, if I do the same thing, I instead get:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2))
```

Anyone got any idea what could be happening differently to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, turns out it was the gem for Scout, removed that and the error goes away!

https://github.com/scoutapp/scout_apm_ruby

Comment: I would venture to say that ruby 3 still has some kwarg issues. I've have it happen in random specs with default rails 6 stuff.

Comment: Thank you, I've been racking my brains trying to figure out why "find" works locally but not on Heroku. Turns out it's Scout.